Partial glowing transparent grid on logo
I want to create a partial glowing grid on a logo as in this video: https://youtu.be/ril9RQmegR0
Can anyone help me?
thank you!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Maybe give a Wireframe modifier to your object, and enable the Bloom option if you are in Eevee until Blender 3. Since Blender 4 Bloom doesn't exist anymore and you need to use a Filter > Glare node in the Compositor:

